# how to test firebase App Check and reCaptcha v3

Tags: firebase, recaptcha, firebase-app-check

I just added reCAPTCHA v3 to my project.

Also did all neccesery stuff at firebase, like allowed firebase App Check atc.

At this point I`m sending App Check token with cloud funtion, like here https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/cloud-functions

I allways get app token Valid. How can i test if it's invalid. Also why i added reCAPTCHA to firebase App Check? Is reCAPTCHA generating the App Token? I`m so confused after all day. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recaptcha in this scenario is used to validate it's *your* web site making the call. Since this is using reCAPTCHA v3, your users won't even notice it is being used. It works invisibly to establish the identity of your app/site.

To test without a valid token, you can try to call the Cloud Function from any other web site, for example one where you didn't implement the reCAPTCHA.

Comment: So this means, if some developer decides to call my onCall cloud function with bot multiple times, he will be rejected right? Because of validation token and reCAPTCHA?

Comment: If their code is not running in your web site, it will indeed be rejected - as their request won't be signed with an App Check token that is valid for your project.